# SQL to find records by ID that have value of only zero in separate column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tricky part here is that some records are duplicate ID's (API) and can contain zero or greater than zero in Lst_30 column.  If there are duplicate API's then I need to do a max on Lst_30 and skip the records if greater than zero.  So in other words, I only want ID's who's Lst_30 values were NOT greater than zero.  I hope I explained it right.

Here is some example data and in this case API (17031236100000 and 17031236100000) are the only records that should get returned:

```
API             LST_30
17031236030000  0
17031236030000  579.727460485171
17031236070000  2027.485
17031236080000  1472.838
17031236100000  0
17031236100000  0
17031236110000  2251.653
17031236120000  282.14245094328
17031236120000  0
17031236130000  0
17031236130000  0
17031236140000  1728.11885164476
```

My stab at it below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT A.API, A.LST_30, B_1.Count
FROM dbo.InProduction AS A 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, LST_30d FROM dbo.InProduction AS B 
                WHERE (LST_30 = 0) GROUP BY LST_30) AS B_1 
                ON A.LST_30 = B_1.LST_30 
    WHERE (B_1.Count > 1) OR (B_1.Count = 1) ORDER BY A.API
```

Comment: Please add some data and what the result should be.  On SQL Fiddle perhaps.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Let's say `API = 1` has two records `LST_30 = 0` and `LST_30 = 1`, what would you want returned for this?

Comment: Apologies @Md.SumanKabir, I'm using SQL Server 2012 standard 64bit edition

Comment: @AaronDietz, there would be no records returned for that case.  Only need records where the LST_30 is only 0 and never any higher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find APIs that have `LST_30 = 0`, then use `NOT EXISTS()` to rule out APIs that also have `LST_30 > 1`:

```
SELECT API, LST_30, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.InProduction P
WHERE LST_30 = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM dbo.InProduction P2
                WHERE P.API = P2.API
                AND P2.LST_30 > 0)
GROUP BY API, LST_30
```

That is assuming you still want the `COUNT(*)`, but if not you can remove that part:

```
SELECT DISTINCT API
FROM dbo.InProduction P
WHERE LST_30 = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM dbo.InProduction P2
                WHERE P.API = P2.API
                AND P2.LST_30 > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this.

```
SELECT API FROM InProduction
GROUP BY API
HAVING COUNT(*)>1 AND SUM(LST_30) =0
```

Comment: I was going to answer similarly though I would use `min(lst_30) = 0 and max(lst_30) = 0` to avoid issues with negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option with positive logic:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT A.API, A.LST_30, B_1.Count
    FROM dbo.InProduction AS A 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT API, SUM(LST_30) AS SumLST30, COUNT(*) AS Count
                    FROM dbo.InProduction B
                    GROUP BY API) AS B_1 
                    ON A.API = B_1.API
        WHERE (B_1.SumLST30 <= 0) 
        ORDER BY A.API
```